# Boot strapper for VSTO 3.0 SP1

Tags: installation, vsto, bootstrapper

I've got a .net 3.5 vs2008 Excel addin.

I've created an installer for it and have it working apart from the fact that I cant get an option in the prerequisites for VSTO 3.0 SP1.

I have one for VSTO 3.0 and when I check the C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\VSTOR30 directory it has

vstor30.exe
vstor30sp1-KB949258-x86.exe
product.xml
"en" directory.

However when I build the installer only the vstor.exe file gets copied over to the bin directory. I need vstor3.0sp1 for the addin to work.
If I manually install vstor sp1 then everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Got it working, I found Bootstrapper manifest generator. http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/bmg

This allows you to package up an exe and I used that as a prerequisite. works well. Only down side is that its not good at realising its already installed and tries again. Not the end of the world though